# Share content across pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise for a Publishing site.

If I have a piece of content (row from a list), how do I display a different view of that content on different pages? e.g.

On the homepage I might want to have a feature link to that content, so I only show its title and summary. When you click on the feature link it takes you to a page dedicated to that content where all its fields are displayed.

Now if I update the content's title I want both the feature and dedicated page to reflect the change. This seems like best practice to me, keeping content separate from pages/presentation, but I'm struggling to find any SharePoint resources that promote this. The Publishing site seems to encourage storing content within the page itself. It seems the "Content Search Web Part" might be the way forward.

I'm new to SharePoint and would like to know the SharePoint way.

To be clear, I'm not talking about SharePoint's "Reusable content" feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wanna go with Content Search Web part you may try **Content Query Web part**, this would help you achieve your required functionality.

[Displaying Custom Fields in a SharePoint 2013 Content Query Web Part](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/displaying-custom-fields-sharepoint-2013-content-query-web-part/)

[Customizing the Content Query Web Part and Item Style](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756834/Customizing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-and-Item-St)

[How to Display Custom Fields in Content Query WebPart in Sharepoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/86aff8/how-to-display-custom-fields-in-content-query-webpart-in-sha/)

Also there are many types of **List View** available, which you can customise and display on Home Page

[Create a custom list view using SharePoint Designer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-list-view-using-SharePoint-Designer-d0de3aa0-5e70-4ae9-bfd1-7e03a599bc73)

[Customize the rendering of a List View in Sharepoint 2013: Displaying List Items in Accordion](https://blog.vgrem.com/2013/04/14/customize-the-rendering-of-a-list-view-in-sharepoint-2013-displaying-list-items-in-accordion/)

You can use **XSLT** approach **Data View webpart** using SharePoint Designer

[SharePoint 2013 – Add DataView WebPart with SharePoint Designer 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/12/sharepoint-2013-add-dataview-webpart-with-sharepoint-designer-2013/)

If you are good with **CSOM or rest**, HTML and CSS, you can write query to fetch row from list and display same using HTML and CSS

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

[Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)

You can use any approach mentioned above and achieve your functionality. If you are still stuck at some part or need code for the same, comment for the same

Comment: That's a lot of ways to achieve the same thing. Is there any best practice/common way for separating content from presentation? A publishing site seems to encourage storing content in the page itself. This seems wrong to me.

Comment: You can choose any based on your comfort level. Content Query Web Part or Data View web part would do for you with minimum efforts. 
I didn't get what did you mean by "Saving content into page itself for publishing site".

Comment: Say an "Article page (image on left)" was created about squares. A content author adds an image of a square and types content directly in to the page content. It would seem this content is locked in to the page. How can the square content be used in other contexts as it's just an image and text on a page, rather than being it's own entity with its own metadata. This is my current understanding which could be wrong.